# Liveagent: the consol does not refresh

Tags: liveagent, refresh, custom-service-console

I'm using the Liveagent console.
In the org ChatTest1 it worked fine: while the client was chatting with the operator he could see all the "actions" that the client was doing. The informations related to some objects ("Transcript" and another custom one) are updated automatically.

In the org ChatTest2 where we are now the refresh does not work anymore.

Has someone had the same issue? Do you know some possible solution?